# showing truncated array when checking unique values in a column of pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, unique, truncation

when checking for list of unique values in a column of **total_sqft** of from this bengaluru housing data https://www.kaggle.com/amitabhajoy/bengaluru-house-price-data my array which is showing list of unique values are truncated.
can any one guide me to show all the list of unique values with out truncation.
i loaded this csv data in to dataframe named as df

```
df['total_sqft'].unique()
```

output is showing like this

```
array(['1056', '2600', '1440', ..., '1133 - 1384', '774', '4689'],
      dtype=object)
```

but when i checked

```
df['total_sqft'].nunique()
```

there are 2117 unique values

Comment: same problem here

Comment: try `list(df['total_sqft'].unique())`